# Android - Geo-fence does not work, using coarse_location

Tags: location, geofencing, android-geofence

I am using the geo-fencing example available at the android developer site.
The geo-fence detection works only if the GPS is turned on, although I am using Coarse Location.
The radius is set to 1000 meters too.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected. Location Services geofences will only work with "fine" location permissions and with location services set to "battery saving" or "high accuracy". "Device only" mode does not work.

> To use geofencing, your app must request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html